# Why Windows 7 uses some old Win98 Icons?

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons

I've been browsing the `system32` folder and noticed a lot of old icons used in Windows 7. Take a look at these:

[image: Old Win98 Icons]

I've seen these in Windows 98, and probably they are even older. Even the `write.exe` ( Which is Microsoft WordPad ) uses old an icon.

Now I haven't checked Windows 10, but I guess they might be there too. What are these doing in Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

Mostly it's probably just a matter of Microsoft spending resources on other things that it believes will bring it more market share against its competition or fulfilll long term business goals.

There's really no technical reason other than "if it ain't broke, don't fix it
" - hence why the portion of the Windows control panel where you add machines to the domain looks the same as it did in 1993, even in Windows 10.